# Convert only time part in android from string to time

Tags: java, time

I need to convert a time stamp that currently is in string format "08.00" to a valid time in java so I later can compare time. How do I convert this string to time?

Comment: "Android" tag seems redundant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        Date date = sdf.parse(time);
```

Comment: @MTplus - the Date class is old now and largely deprecated, and I'm pretty sure if you print `date` here, it will assume 01/01/70, so be wary of that.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and/or [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) classes, perhaps consider [**LocalTime**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

```
String time = "08:00";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(time);
System.out.println(lt);
```

Output:

> 08:00

And can compare to other times easily with [`LocalTime::isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) or [`LocalTime::isAfter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-)

**[Example](https://ideone.com/8wd7Dc)**

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
String time = "08.00"; 
try {
    DateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm");
    Date date = sdfInput.parse(time);

    DateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Log.e( "Time: ", sdfOutput.format(date));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Output ->  Time: 08:00

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is with a SimplDateFormatter:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
```

Then you can call  `Date date = sdf.parse(*your time string*)`

Now you have your time as a valid Date object.

Answer (score 0):

I have timeformat like this hhmmss="151918" 
so you can use any format instead of hhmmss according to your current time format like
"hh.mm" or hh:mm:ss etc
 and you can call this method form any where you needed.

```
 fun convertTimeFormat(time:String):String{
        var formattedTime=""
        try {
            val inputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss")
            val timeObj = inputFormat.parse(time)
            Log.d("timeObj",""+timeObj)
            formattedTime=SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").format(timeObj)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return formattedTime
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Also it doesn’t seem to answer the question, which was about getting objects that could be compared. Finally I think that your method gives a wrong result if the string was `121918`. You need to watch the case of the format pattern letters. There’s a difference between `hh` and `HH`.