# how do I compare time part from Date in java

Tags: java, android, date

I need to compare the time part from 2 date/time variables to see if the time is inbetween the current time in android. How can I do that?

```
    Boolean InBetweenTime(Date currentTime, Date StartTime, Date EndTime)
{
    Boolean result = false;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if ((!currentTime.before(StartTime))&&(!currentTime.after(EndTime))){
        //between time
    } else {
        //not inbetween time
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show what you've already tried

Comment: Explain better your problem please.

Comment: You asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929034/convert-only-time-part-in-android-from-string-to-time/52929217#52929217) earlier with no attempt, got your answer, and now you're asking your next question with no attempt. Please provide a [mcve] this time, and show your own attempt! Plus I gave you an example of how to compare times on your earlier question...

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929034/convert-only-time-part-in-android-from-string-to-time to this

Comment: If you want to check if a date is in a range of 2 other dates, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range).

Comment: Read the javadocs of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and maybe some examples, there are a lot of them in the www...

Comment: I have this so far...

Comment: Boolean InBetweenTime(Date currentTime, Date StartTime, Date EndTime)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if ((currentTime.before(StartTime))&&(currentTime.after(EndTime))){
            //time is inbetween
        } else {
            //time is not inbetween
        }
        return result;
    }

Comment: I recommend you learn to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. [Tutorial link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). To use it on not-new Android, add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project.

Comment: Assuming that start time is before end time, for current time to be between them it needs to be *after start* time and *before end* time, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm trying to stick to API level 15 for compability reasons and cannot use LocalTime, the above code would work if I only could compare the time part instead of the whole date/time.

Comment: Though I have not got the experience I strongly believe that [the ThreeTenABP library that I already linked to once](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) is all you need to use `LocalTime` on API level 15.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to compare only time, ignoring date, then you should do something like this, so your 'date' part be equal in all three variables.

```
Boolean InBetweenTime(Date currentTime, Date startTime, Date endTime){
    Boolean result = false;

    //calendar for currentTime
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentCal.setTime(currentTime);
    //calendar for startTime
    Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal.setTime(startTime);
    //calendar for endTime
    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCal.setTime(endTime);
    //set corresponding date fields of startTime and endTime to be equal t ocurrentTime, so you compare only time fields
    startCal.set(currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    endCal.set(currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    //return true if between, false otherwise
    return (!currentTime.before(startCal.getTime())) && (!currentTime.after(endCal.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the time part of a Date (which is a date/time value), use this:

```
Date date = ...
Instant instant = d.toInstant();
Instant midnight = instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Duration timeSinceMidnight = Duration.between(midnight, instant);
System.out.println(timeSinceMidnight);
```

Comment: This gives us midnight in UTC. Most will want midnight in their own time zone. Also it's not so straightforward to compare `Duration` objects, which was wanted in rhe question. Better to get a `LocalTime`. But good that you are using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using java.time API (Java 8+)

The solution would be clean and clear using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(isBetween(Instant.parse("2022-11-20T20:30:00Z"), Instant.parse("2022-11-15T23:45:00Z")));
        System.out.println(isBetween(Instant.parse("2022-11-20T10:20:30Z"), Instant.parse("2022-11-15T20:10:05Z")));
        System.out.println(isBetween(Instant.parse("2022-11-20T10:20:30Z"), Instant.parse("2022-11-15T10:20:30Z")));
    }

    static boolean isBetween(Instant startInstant, Instant endInstant) {
        LocalTime currentTime = getTime(Instant.now());
        LocalTime startTime = getTime(startInstant);
        LocalTime endTime = getTime(endInstant);
        return currentTime.isAfter(startTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime);
    }

    static LocalTime getTime(Instant instant) {
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
    }
}
```

**Output when I ran it at ~ 2022-11-30T23:32:00Z**:

```
true
false
false
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Solution using Java version < 8

If your project is open to using 3rd party library for date-time, I recommend you check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/10819573). The ThreeTenABP library makes it possible to backport `java.time` API to Java 6 and 7.

If you want to stick to the standard library of Java version < 8, here is a solution:

The trick is to **set today's year, month and day into the startDate and endDate** and then you can compare them as usual. If you have year, month and day the same across all three instances of `Date`, basically you comparing just their times.

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Tests
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(isBetween(sdf.parse("2022-11-20T20:30:00Z"), sdf.parse("2022-11-15T23:45:00Z")));
        System.out.println(isBetween(sdf.parse("2022-11-20T10:20:30Z"), sdf.parse("2022-11-15T20:10:05Z")));
        System.out.println(isBetween(sdf.parse("2022-11-20T10:20:30Z"), sdf.parse("2022-11-15T10:20:30Z")));
    }

    static boolean isBetween(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
        Date currentTime = new Date();
        // System.out.println(currentTime);
        Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentCal.setTime(currentTime);
        int year = currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = currentCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set today's year, month and day into the startDate
        Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCal.setTime(startTime);
        startCal.set(year, month, day);
        startTime = startCal.getTime();
        // System.out.println(startTime);

        // Set today's year, month and day into the endDate
        Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.setTime(endTime);
        endCal.set(year, month, day);
        endTime = endCal.getTime();
        // System.out.println(endTime);

        return currentTime.after(startTime) && currentTime.before(endTime);
    }
}
```

**Output when I ran it at ~ 2022-11-30T23:33:00Z**:

```
true
false
false
```